# Plotting points in a grid formation

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, plot, grid

I'm trying to plot points on a graph given the X and Y coordinates of a single point. X and Y will both be integers between 1 and 9 (inclusive), and the graph should have each axis of size 9. I'm trying to do this using ASC11 characters, and I'm using the constants: width (X axis size) and height (Y axis size):

```
#define WIDTH 9
#define HEIGHT 9
```

I'm trying to get the graph to look like a 9x9 grid and it asks the user for input on which block they would like to plot a x on. So if they put 3,4 it would go 3 over (X) and 4 up (Y). How would I plot something like that using for loops and if statements?

Answer (score 0):

Write pseudo-code first:

```
Fill character array with blanks;
Put plot point into array;
Output;
```

Then some code like the sketch below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        characterArray [i][j] = ' ';
    }
}

int x = 2;  // 3 - 1 = 2 for zero-based indexing.
int y = 3;  // 4 - 1 = 3.
characterArray [x][y] = '*';
```

Is this a homework question?

Comment: Yes a part 3 of a 3 part homework question. I have struggled with outputting pictures/graphs/designs with code all year. It just confuses me for some reason.

Comment: We are supposed to output a grid out of "-" "+" and "|" like:                                +---+---+                                                                                                              |     |     |                                                                                                             +---+---+